# color Image displaying in grayscale in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, image, stream

I have the stream of image bytes taken from the pdf file.
I need to display it in Windows forms. so, I decoded it and convert the stream into image and then print the image.

The colored image is displayed in gray scale

[image]

This is the original image.

[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: It's hard to help you if we don't know the code you used to decode and display the image.

Comment: please add comment for negative vote...

Comment: @UthistranS.: You did not provide constructive information on what you have as input, and how you want it to work. Also, no code.

Comment: @Neolisk: Fine,,,, will be doing better in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the image.....
Let me explain it:

While decoding the string to stream initially, I used some `Encoding` techniques and then decoded to the image... There I made the mistake...
Then cleared it off just by converting the string to `ASCII` char bytes and then decoded it to image....Now it works good with the color and what I expected....